# JAVA: GUI not showing until mouse hovers over?

Tags: java, user-interface, look-and-feel

I am trying out different look and feels in Java and I have added system look and feel but my GUI components aren't visible until I hover over them? This is the code where I change my look and feel:

```
try{
    Base base = new Base();
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

and here is the code for the GUI components:

```
private void HomeScreen(){
    frame.getContentPane().removeAll();

    JButton btnNewNote = new JButton("");
    btnNewNote.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnNewNote.setIcon(new ImageIcon("res/images/NewNote.png"));
    btnNewNote.setBounds(385, 29, 34, 34);
    btnNewNote.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewNote);
}
```

everything works fine except I have to hover over my gui elements for them to become visible. Could anyone give me a reason why

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Swing components (except top level containers like JFrame) are visible by default, so there is no need to make the button visible.

Answer (score 3):

When removing and re-adding components from a container you must call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the container after making the changes.

Other issues:

- You appear to be using a null layout, and if so, don't. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- The easiest way to "swap" views is via a CardLayout -- please check this out.